# Is there a decent algorithm to find the approximate wasted space in a Packing scenario?

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

Say we have a rectangular space of length *L* and width *W*. We now have to pack as many regular polygons of area A inside of this rectangle. This is a pretty well known problem and it's been asked a bit before, however what is different here is that I do not care the location of the packing, all that matters would be the approximate used or wasted space.

Also important to note is that we cannot change the size of anything.

I'm not sure if this has been done before, or if this could make the algorithm/approximation more efficient, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean, "We now have to pack as _many_ regular polygons of area A inside of this rectangle."

Comment: the wasted space should probably be less than 0.2146 * L * W

Comment: Define "wasted space."

Comment: I define wasted space as space not containing a shape that we've packed

Comment: I'm also looking for this answer, but isn't it (lengthOutsidebox x widthOutsidebox x heightOutsidebox) minus (lengthInsidebox x widthInsidebox x heightInsidebox)